# Add two torch tensor list

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to add two PyTorch tensors together, for example, let

```
a = tensor([[1., 1., 2.],
            [1., 1., 2.],
            [1., 1., 2.],
            [1., 1., 2.],
            [1., 1., 2.],
            [1., 1., 2.]])

b = tensor([[4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
            [4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
            [4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
            [4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
            [4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
            [4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.]])
```

And I would like the resulting tensor `c` to be:

```
c = tensor([[5., 6., 8., 8., 9., 11.],
            [5., 6., 8., 8., 9., 11.],
            [5., 6., 8., 8., 9., 11.],
            [5., 6., 8., 8., 9., 11.],
            [5., 6., 8., 8., 9., 11.],
            [5., 6., 8., 8., 9., 11.]])
```

Note: `b.shape[1]` is always a multiple of `a.shape[1]`.

is there any better way than the solution below solution?

```
fin =  torch.Tensor()
for i in range(int(b.shape[1]/a.shape[1])):
    target = b[:,batch*i:batch*(i+1)]
    temp = torch.add(target, a)
    fin = torch.cat([fin, temp], dim =1)
c = fin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the columns of `a` to match the shape of `b` with [`torch.Tensor.repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html), then add the resulting tensor to `b`:

```
>>> b + a.repeat(1, b.size(1)//a.size(1))
tensor([[ 5.,  6.,  8.,  8.,  9., 11.],
        [ 5.,  6.,  8.,  8.,  9., 11.],
        [ 5.,  6.,  8.,  8.,  9., 11.],
        [ 5.,  6.,  8.,  8.,  9., 11.],
        [ 5.,  6.,  8.,  8.,  9., 11.],
        [ 5.,  6.,  8.,  8.,  9., 11.]])
```

Comment: wow thx. what a simple solution